# binary index tree implementation so as to calculate number of integrs less than a given number in a given interval?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

given an array , how can i calculate and store number of elements less  than a given number in a given interval .

e.g.  if array is `{2 6 3 5 2}`  and given is the interval `{2 4}` and integer is 6 then answer should be  3  
 3 5 2  are less than 6.

please see intervals start from 1.

earlier i tried doing this thing by using segment tree but was not able to come up with any solution.

can any one suggest what could be done ?

i tried to read the topcoder tutorials on BIT as well .

is there any classical algorithm for doing this.

Comment: Array maybe modified beetween queries or it is static?

Comment: also please provide size of array, and possible amout of queries. Max value of array items.

Comment: @Толя size of array can be 2*10^5 and so are the queries.actually queries are to find the total number of inversions in the array if i swap two elements of array.

Comment: As I make sense, we need found a inversions diff, and after query array is changed or restored into initial state?

Comment: i am not sure that whether inversion diffrence will make it. but i thought to count the number of intial inversions and then i dont know if i swap two elements then how many elements are affected .if u can suggest me something then please and is BIT  a gud approach to solve this problem.

Comment: it is restored in initial state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some searching and thinking i found that it can be done with the help of BIT and offline processing .
 this link will be helpful    http://pavelsimo.blogspot.in/2012/09/counting-inversions-in-array-using-BIT.html

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we are trying to access a database to find times when a price was less than a given number in a given time interval.

### OFFLINE PROCESSING

If you have a number of queries that can be processed all together then you can use this approach:

```
For each query for an interval between a and b, store a and b in a sorted dictionary that maps from the important times (a and b) to the query

For each price in time order:
    Add the price to a Binary Indexed Tree (BIT) 
    Use the sorted dictionary to find all queries that can now be answered
    For each of these queries use the BIT to count the number of elements less than the number
```

This answers queries in O( (n+q)(log(q)+log(n)) ) where n is the number of elements, and q is the number of queries

### ONLINE PROCESSING

If you have incoming queries that need to be processed one at a time, then you could consider using a [KD-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) to store the elements in a 2d data structure that can be rapidly searched.

Comment: can u please elaborate it

Answer (score 1):

using segment tree,

> Each node of the tree contains the sorted array of elements within the range

Building the segment tree 
1. All the leaf nodes contains single elements so they are already sorted.

2. Can use `std::merge`,(c++) that combines the elements in the sorted ranges efficiently.

Thus you can construct the segment tree recursively. 
During each query, use binary search to find the position of the `number n`, `std::lowerbound`(c++) serves for this purpose well.

'k = position of element >= n in the range' 
clearly there are `k values` less than n in the current tree segment.

Answer (score 0):

> e.g. if array is {2 6 3 5 2} and given is the interval {2 4} and integer is 6 then answer should be 3
>   3 5 2 are less than 6.

If i understand your question correctly, i don't really see use of extreme data structure for this (*it would be an overkill actually*) an array with a single pass is more than sufficient to solve this problem.

a simple way would be to loop from *lower interval* and go on till *highest interval* while comparing numbers during traversing.

```
//array = {2 6 3 5 2} 
//interval = {a,b}
//number = n

for(int i = a;i<=b;i++)
   if(arr[i] < n)
     count++; /* OR system.out.println(arr[i]+" "); */
```

This is done in O(1) memory and O(b-a) time complexity

Comment: answer should be 3. 3 5 2 is a hint to answer, required output only count.

Comment: @Толя : yes...thats why i placed `SOP` in `OR` ....final output is stored in variable `count` :)

Comment: If required search a count instead of array, nothing guaranted that faster than O(N) does not exists.

Comment: @Толя : and from where will you get the count...?? :) my solution says `O(b-a)`, this would be equal to `O(N)` in worst case! :)

Comment: With precalculation. Right now I does not have a solution as need a bit clarify problem statement.

Comment: @Толя : even for `precalculation`, you'll have to traverse array once i assume unless you some good *guessing* algo....waiting for your solution though! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor you are right but this cant be done for 10^5 queries on a array of 10^5